# Where to store currently selected item id?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to write an asp.net app which searches a sql db and returns/updates the data.

I want to be able to hold the currently selected id of the item my user has selected. For example a doctors surgery would select a patient record then be able to browse the app without having to re-select that patient on each page.

What would be the best way to do this. Ideally I need to be able to get this ID application wide. the only thing i can think of is to create a public class, store the id and make it public but this seems quite messy

Thank you

Comment: Creating a public class will not make the ID accessible throughout your application. Making it public is an accessibility modifier, and will only change the scope within it's implementation that it is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a Cookie or a Session variable.

Cookie info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Session Info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing it in a session variable:

```
Page.Session["CurrentPatient"] = YourPatient record
```

To get the record you would use:

```
YourPatientRecord = Page.Session["CurrentPatient"] as PatientRecord;
```

To make things easier I usually create a property in the page or base page to use throughout the system.

eg:

```
protected PatientRecord CurrentPatient
{
  get
  {
    return Session["CurrentPatient"] as PatientRecord;
  }
  set
  {
    Session["CurrentPatient"] = value;
  }
}
```

Then to use it in the page it would simply be:

```
PatientRecord oPatientRecord = this.CurrentPatient;
```